# How to pause/resume an already running function with another function call?

Tags: javascript, html

After the window is loaded, a function is called using the event `onload=""`.

I have another event, `onclick=""`, which should pause or resume the previous function whenever I click on the window.

I read 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831132/javascript-how-to-pause-resume-function)
thread and implemented the logic for pause/resume functionality but for some reason the previous function was not paused/resumed.

My `html` and `javascript` code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var started = false;
        var timer;
        function initialize(){
          do something...

          timer = setInterval(move,15);

          function move(){ //it animates, it moves div elements on the window
            do something...
          }
        }
        function pauseResume(){ //it should pause the elements and resume 
                                //from the same coordinate(x,y)
                                //shouldn't resume the animation from the begining
          if(started){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            started = false;
          }else{
            initialize();
            started = true;
          }
        }
   </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize();">
      <div onclick="pauseResume(event);"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Can't use jQuery or any other javaScript libraries. Is there something wrong with my implementation?

Comment: I haven't looked in detail, but this is wrong: `var timer = setInterval(move,15);` - you need to remove the `var`, so that it references the `timer` in the outer scope. The way you have it now, the `clearInterval` will not clear the timer.

Answer (score 1):

i agree with a Robin comment, I would rewrite the code to this way:

```
var started = false;
var timer;
function initialize(){
  do something...
  timer = setInterval(move,15);
}

function move(){ //it animates, it moves div elements on the window
    do something...
}
function pauseResume(){ //it should pause the elements and resume 
                        //from the same coordinate(x,y)
                        //shouldn't resume the animation from the begining
  if(started){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    started = false;
  }else{
    initialize();
    started = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: that was a typo, I edited the code. The problem is when I click on the window the animation(movement of the div elements) pauses but when I click again to resume, the animation starts from the beginning. Do you have any clue how to resume the animation from the exact point where it was paused?

Comment: @007mrviper you need to save the current state of your animation process. Whatever information you have which would be needed to continue the next step (e.g. coordinates or anything else) needs to be stored at the point of pausing in such a way that you can retrieve it next time you resume. This is basically what all games and programs of that type do when you save a game. In your case you could put the data in a simple global object, or in localstorage or something like that.

Comment: I got you, you need to see this [article](https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/) there are a lot of examples of how to build such animations